# If $x^n = f(x)g(x)$ as complex polynomials, must $f,g$ be of the form $x^m$?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

If $x^n = f(x)g(x)$ as complex polynomials, must $f,g$ be of the form $x^m$?

i.e. $x^n = x^mx^l$ where $m+l = n$.

This is quite trivial, but I want to make sure I didn't miss anything.

**Attempt**: If $f$ wasn't of the form $x^m$, and has degree $d$, the fundamental theorem of algebra says it has $d$ roots counted with multiplicity. One of these roots must be nonzero since $f$ isn't of the form $x^m$. But the left hand side of the equation would be nonzero when evaluated at that root.

Comment: Um, is there a question here...It sounds like you got everything covered...

Comment: @Gina - Nothing is missing from my attempt right? Ok, I will delete this soon.

Comment: If anything I would elaborate on why one of the roots must be nonzero. I also added the proof-verification tag. It is very useful for questions like this.

Comment: You should add that $f$ and $g$ must be monic polynomials, otherwise any choice like $f(x)=\lambda x^{n-m},g(x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}x^m$ would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use induction. I assume you are looking for monic polynomials $f,g$.

Since $x^n$ vanishes in zero, at least one polynomial between $f$ and $g$ must vanish in zero, hence you have $f= x\cdot f_1$ or $g=x\cdot g_1$ and the problem boils down to proving the statement with $n-1$ in place of $n$. Since the statement holds for $n=1$, we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Although your proof is rather swift, I would note that this is true in more general settings, where one cannot invoke FTA, namely that it holds for polynomials over any integral domain (So, of note: integers, rationals, reals, finite fields). In the general case, we simply use the fact that in a product of polynomials, the products of the highest non-zero terms, and lowest non-zero terms, are the only contributors to the respective terms in the products, in particular for $l \leq m, n \leq p$ we have

$$(a_lx^l + ... + a_nx^n)(b_mx^m + ... +b_px^p) = a_lb_mx^{l+m} + \text{terms of intermediary orders} + a_nb_px^{n+p}$$

Since we know the product has a single non-zero term we have $n = l, m = p$

Disclaimer: I suppose if one really desired (and was okay with pulling out AOC when needed) you could embed any integral domain in the algebraic closure of its fraction field, but that seems a bit much.

Comment: You can get away without the axiom of choice in your final comment; just use splitting fields.

Answer (score 0):

As @JHance points out, the statement is true for any constant field $k$, not just $\mathbb C$. But I think the best argument is the one that calls in the fact that $k[x]$ is a Unique Factorization Domain, plus the manifest fact that $x$ is an indecomposable (irreducible) in that ring. So any factorization of $x^m$ must involve only associates $\lambda x$ of $x$, where $\lambda$ is allowed to be a unit. But in $k[x]$, the only units are the nonzero constants $\lambda$.